# non linear system solving

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I have the following system :
$$\begin{cases}2x-w-2d=0\\
2y-w+d=0\\
w(x+y-6)=0\\
d(2x-y-4)=0\end{cases}$$
I used to solve linear equations using pivots but i don't think this will work with this system , so I need a method to follow to solve this system

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: If the system is non linear we can use the the basic operations algebraics such as find a variable based on another, substituting, etc.

Comment: If $w=0$ and $d=0$ the last two equations are certainly true and you only have to solve the first two, which are linear.  If $w=0$ and $d\ne0$ then the third is true and the fourth is $2x-y-4=0$ which together with the first two is again a linear system.  And similarly for other cases.

Comment: we have 16 case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two equations tell you the solution is contained in a plane in $\mathbb{R}^4$. Notice that, by the nature of the last two equations, it is convenient to express $w$ and $d$ in terms of $x$ and $y$. Once you will do this, you will find out that:
$$ \Sigma_1 : \begin{cases}w = \frac{2}{3}(x + 2y)\\
d = \frac{2}{3}(x - y)
\end{cases}.
$$
Now, substitute in the last two equations. You will get the following system in the variables $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$:
$$ \Sigma_2 : \begin{cases}
(x + 2y)(x + y - 6) = 0\\
(x - y)(2x - y - 4) = 0
\end{cases} .
$$
So, it corresponds to the intersection of pairs of lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$ between the four that appear in the system! So actually, you need to find the solution to solve:
$$ \begin{cases} x + 2y = 0\\
x - y = 0
\end{cases} \quad \land \quad \begin{cases}
x + 2y = 0\\
2x - y - 4 = 0
\end{cases} \quad \land \quad \begin{cases}
x + y - 6 = 0\\
x - y = 0
\end{cases} \quad \land \quad \begin{cases}
x + y - 6 = 0\\
x - y = 0
\end{cases}. 
$$
If I am not mistaken, these should give the following couples:
$$ (x,y) = \begin{cases}
(0,0)\\
(-\frac{4}{5},\frac{8}{5})\\
(3,3)\\
(\frac{10}{3}, \frac{8}{3})
\end{cases}.
$$
Now just plug every value obtained into $\Sigma_1$ to find the complete tuples of solutions $(x,y,w,d) \in \mathbb{R}^4$.